# Gravity forms populate from custom fields

Tags: forms, for-loop, gravity

I'm using Gravity Form for event booking.

I created Custom Post Types for the events and each event has custom fields with dates, venues etc...

How can I populate Gravity form with the custom fields of events?

Example:
Custom Post Type 1 - Event 1 - 1st option Date from xxx to xxx / 2nd option date from xxx to xxx
etc

Gravity Form 1 (on another page) - Dropdown menu pre-populated with dates choice.

I've tried with shortcodes but it doesn't work

Thank you
All the best

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/dynamically-populating-drop-down-fields/

If you're not populating choice-based fields but rather text fields (or other single value field types), this will be helpful:

http://gravitywiz.com/dynamic-products-via-post-meta/